# Import daily CSV file from email only updated values into SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, import

Good morning; I currently receive my companies time logs on a daily basis, for the entire week. So for example it's Thursday now so I'll see entries for Monday (7/30) Tuesday (7/31) etc. I would like to just bulk load this into SQL but cannot seem to figure out how. If I use the flatfile import it loads it in in a snap no problems, but can only make a new table on import. I would prefer to just have this only update any new values, perhaps through a temptable and only load into my table "Timelog" the new values from the previous day. This is the flatfile import:

[image: Flat File]

Which is exactly what I want, except two things. I know that even if I could get it to append to an existing table it'll reimport ALL the data again, which is a no go as well as I'll have duplicate values.

This is the CSV File

[image: CSV File]

So I tried to write a bulkinsert statement:

```
BULK INSERT Timelog
FROM '‪C:\Intel\555.csv'
WITH
(
FIRSTROW = 8,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = 'C:\CSVDATA\derrors.csv',
TABLOCK
)
```

This fails because it says it cannot find the file which I have to work on pathing, but I also know this won't work because it's not removing duplicate values. Can anyone help?

Comment: Which errorcode do you get?

Comment: That it can't find CSV file - I'm on a network and SQL server is on separate server so at some point I'll have the file start saving on it's direct C drive to avoid the pathing issue once I get the query working the way I want it too. However if I do the flat file import it finds it in a snap, drops the first 7 rows and everything, but I cannot/ do not know how to access the base sql statement behind it

Comment: It must write an error code when you try to execute

Answer (score 1):

Either you have access problems. If you are on a SERVER and want to go to a direct path on your local PC, obvisouly you cant do that. Your file has to be on the same server as your SQL Server. Unless you specify anything else.

This example here worked for me:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

select @sql = 'BULK INSERT dbo.Timelog FROM ';
select @sql = @sql +'''D:\Test\555csb.csv''';
select @sql = @sql + ' WITH
(

FIRSTROW = 2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '';'',  --CSV field delimiter
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',   --Use to shift the control to next row
ERRORFILE = ''D:\Test\derrors.csv'',TABLOCK)';
print @sql
exec(@sql)
```

**CSV File**

[image]

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply my friend quick question, I receive the CSV from our payroll 3rd party company. They handle all of that for us and can only receive with comma delimited, And will this that you've posted not post duplicate values if I run this same report tomorrow?

Comment: Yes of cause it would. It always takes the entire file and inserts into timelog. Insert your data into a TimeLogTemp which you truncates everytime. And do so merge SQL which only takes the newest records. You cannot incremtal load your csv file, without its being too complex.

Comment: Or you can just truncate your table before inserting the records....It takes it all anyways - Unless you get data in seperate files.

Comment: Sounds good thank you my man! Let me fiddle with for a moment. I appreciate the help greatly!

Comment: Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".  

This is the error I get when running it

Comment: That Could be because of wrong delimiter or datatypes is NOT long enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177296/discussion-between-dave-holt-and-thomas).